# Where is my Clothier?

Tags: terraria

I beat Skeletron and recently learned this is supposed to cause the Clothier to spawn as an NPC, but this didn't happen in my world. How do I get the Clothier to spawn?

Comment: Is this...Terraria?

Answer (score 6):

In order for the Clothier to spawn, ALL of the following must be met:

1. Skeletron must be defeated
2. All NPCs that have spawn requirements met must have a home
3. A vacant home must be available

Once all three are met, give it a few in-game days and he'll arrive. The number one thing I would recommend checking is that [your houses are built correctly](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Home). It would also be a good idea to create a couple extra homes in case one of them isn't built correctly or if there are multiple NPCs waiting to spawn.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a house built with all the correct specifications for the npc to spawn and live there.

Comment: And then wait until the clothier decides that moving in is something good. Just like you have to wait for all other NPCs.

Comment: If you open the menu and hit the housing icon, you can see which NPCs you have and what houses they're assigned to.  It will also tell you if your structure qualifies as a house for the NPC.

Answer (score 1):

A simple plan is to build an "apartment" building.  In order for everyone to have a spot you will want at least 11 "apartments".  This is for housing for all available NPC's and an extra one for you.  The only annoying part of the apartment complex is that goblin/snowmen spawns may kill one or several of the NPC's so that they would have to regenerate.

Comment: With Terraria 1.2 you will want a much larger apartment building, I have had 4 new people move in so far.  (I still have not made one of the new maps hardmode yet, so I do not know who else lurks in the creases.)

Answer (score 1):

After you have defeated Skeletron, you need to go and make a room that is 6 blocks tall and 10 blocks wide. Put a door on one side. Fill the room in with walls. Then place a table, a chair, and at least one torch inside. The floor must be blocks (not platforms), and make sure there is at least three open blocks on the floor that he can walk on.

After you have made that house with those requirements, just wait a bit and he will spawn. After he spawns, then you can improve on making his home look nice and whatnot.